# Should I make minor edit in the code in the question to make it compilable?

Tags: discussion, editing, code

Consider this question: [Parallel arrows along a curve with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469796/parallel-arrows-along-a-curve-with-tikz).

The OP's code is clearly not compilable. The preamble of the code is not shown.

However, we can add a single line

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin = 3mm]{standalone}
```

to the code to make it compilable; and it produces this figure:

[image]

So, in cases like this, should I add the above line to the code and add the picture to the question? Or should I suggest like "Please add an MWE" and wait for the OP to edit the question?

Comment: See also this one: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/previous-editing-and-etiquette-discussions?rq=1

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oh, yes, it is a clear duplicate. Thank you. I'm sorry for not searching enough!

Comment: This one is better: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-and-isnt-it-acceptable-to-edit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [This question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7729/156366) is also related.